# Shader/UVs in Eevee looks different in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I am working on a timer (based on a tutorial by CGMatter), and everything works when I view it in Eevee Rendered view, but when I switch to Cycles, it appears like the shader just stops working, the UVs also appear like they are not transformed anymore like they are in Eevee (see images and blend file below). Does anybody know a solution for this?

[image: Eevee Rendered View]
*Eevee Rendered View* ^^^
[image: Cycles Rendered View]
*Cycles Rendered View* ^^^

Here's [my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2yxzLoXiEcMIs1PCt_k1fQMRW1wBO9K/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Eevee and Cycles are 2 very different engines where cycles works with light bounces and Eevee approximates everything to make it faster... This way you are missing the Bloom effect that is easy to setup in Eevee, if you want the Bloom effect in Cycles, you need to go to composition and add Glare node with Fog glow as an option... for 5 changing to 0, I am not sure because I don't know how are you changing it, is there a way you can share your file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've now attached a blend file (not sure if it works for you because I reckon it requires the image texture as well), you can view the difference when you switch between eevee and cycles, everything with the numbers is basically happening in the shader section.

Comment: You forgot to pack textures, go to File > External data > Pack all into .blend and send it again or send textures as well

Comment: It should now be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is caused by *Material Output* node that sneaked its way to the custom node group:

[image]

Apparently Eevee and Cycles resolve the conflict of multiple *Material Output* nodes differently. Removing this node from your custom node group solves the issue.

Comment: Aah there it is, I was wondering why there is visible material even when I disconnected material output from any values... didn't saw that there is second output

Comment: Aha, I see, thank you so much, I have been looking for a while to resolve this issue.